# Getting the Value of a UITextField as keystrokes are entered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

Let's say I have the following code:

```
IBOutlet UITextField* nameTextField;
IBOutlet UILabel* greetingLabel;
```

I'd like the `greetingLabel` to read "Hello [nameTextField]" as soon as the user presses any key.

What I need basically is the iPhone equivalent of the Cocoa delegate method `controlTextDidChange`.

The `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` delegate method is called each time a keystroke occurs:

```
- (BOOL)              textField:(UITextField *)textField
  shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     
              replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

The string argument returns the character that is pressed. The actual `textField`'s value (`nameTextField.text`) remains blank however.

What am I missing here? (I'd like `nameTextField` to reflect the exact string that the user has entered so far).

Answer (score 199, accepted):

It turns out, the easiest way to do this is using Interface Builder:

- Add a IBAction (to the ViewController, say, as in this case)
- Ctrl-Click (or right click) on the UITextField in Interface Builder
- Connect the "Editing Changed" event to the File's Owner's IBAction added in the first step.

Works like a charm :) (I can't believe I spent numerous days on this, and to realize now that the solution was much simpler than I'd thought :P)

Comment: Thanks! I'd been using "Value Changed" like you'd use with a UISlider, etc. Interesting that they'd have two events which seem to have the same behavior.

Comment: For some reason I still wanted a programatic way to do this... but I gave in... This method Rocks! Thankyou for sharing... I had seen it before but after days of coding my brain is no longer functioning hehe.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw But you can do this in a programatic way ;) Just perform `[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldEditingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]` ;).

Answer (score 102):

you could register an action for the event UIControlEventEditingChanges on the text field:

```
[nameTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(updateLabelUsingContentsOfTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

...

```
// TODO: error checking

- (void)updateLabelUsingContentsOfTextField:(id)sender {

    greetingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", ((UITextField *)sender).text];

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify this using Interface Builder?

Answer (score 11):

`UITextField` has a notification `UITextFieldTextDidChange` which will be fired every time the text changes if you register for it. Just register for that notification and in the method called by the notification, change the label's text.

To add to this, the object passed to your notification handler will have the text of the `UITextField`.

Hope that helps.