# Using `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`, how do I get the text including the current typed character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm using the code below to try and have `textField2`'s text content get updated to match `textField1`'s whenever the user types in `textField1`.

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {    
  if (theTextField == textField1){    
     [textField2 setText:[textField1 text]];    
  }
}
```

However, the output I observe is that...

> textField2 is "12", when textField1 is "123"
>
> textField2 is "123", when textField1 is "1234"

... when what I want is:

> textField2 is "123", when textField1 is "123"
>
> textField2 is "1234", when textField1 is "1234"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a reminder it is staggeringly easier to always use the **"Editing Changed" event** .. just drag it in IB to a function you make.

Comment: Note the editing changed event does not capture any text changing events generated programmatically, e.g. autocorrect/autocompletion/text replacement.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

`-shouldChangeCharactersInRange` gets called **before** text field actually changes its text, that's why you're getting old text value. To get the text after update use:

```
[textField2 setText:[textField1.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];
```

Comment: This *almost* worked for me.  If I typed a character, this worked.  If I pressed the delete button, it'd delete two characters.  For me, the following suggestion worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388237/getting-the-value-of-a-uitextfield-as-keystrokes-are-entered    Basically, drag'n'drop from the UITextField into your code (to create a function), then right-click on your TextField, and drag'n'drop from the circle for the "Editing Changed" to your new function.  (Sigh.  I miss Visual Studio sometimes..)

Comment: I also feel this is a valid answer, but not THE answer. The best way to accomplish what you want was answered by @tomute

Comment: Or 
textFiel.text = (textFiel.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

in Swift

Comment: @MikeGledhill You can do the same thing programmatically: `[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldEditingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]`

Answer (score 54):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString * searchStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSLog(@"%@",searchStr);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 43):

## Swift 3

Based on the accepted answer, the following should work in **Swift 3**:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newString = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    return true
}
```

### Note

Both `String` and `NSString` have methods called `replacingCharacters:inRange:withString`. However, as expected, the former expects an instance of `Range`, while the latter expects an instance of `NSRange`. The `textField` delegate method uses an `NSRange` instance, thus the use of `NSString` in this case.

Comment: `replacingCharacters` should be `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`

Comment: @Alan_s I copied this snippet directly from my Xcode project and it was working fine. Are you using Xcode 8.1 with target to iOS 10.1?

Answer (score 26):

Instead of using the UITextFieldDelegate, try to use ["Editing Changed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388237/getting-the-value-of-a-uitextfield-as-keystrokes-are-entered) event of UITextField.

Answer (score 15):

In Swift(4), without `NSString` (pure Swift):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let textFieldString = textField.text, let swtRange = Range(range, in: textFieldString) {

        let fullString = textFieldString.replacingCharacters(in: swtRange, with: string)

        print("FullString: \(fullString)")
    }

    return true
}
```

As an extension:

```
extension UITextField {

    func fullTextWith(range: NSRange, replacementString: String) -> String? {

        if let fullSearchString = self.text, let swtRange = Range(range, in: fullSearchString) {

            return fullSearchString.replacingCharacters(in: swtRange, with: replacementString)
        }

        return nil
    }
}

// Usage:

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let textFieldString = textField.fullTextWith(range: range, replacementString: string) {
        print("FullString: \(textFieldString)")
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift version for it :**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if string == " " {
        return false
    }

    let userEnteredString = textField.text

    var newString = (userEnteredString! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as NSString

    print(newString)

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the code you need,

```
if ([textField isEqual:self.textField1])
  textField2.text = [textField1.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

Answer (score 1):

use guard

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard case let textFieldString as NSString = textField.text where
            textFieldString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string).length <= maxLength else {
                return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(copyText:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Don't forget to call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` in `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace the textfield text with this you can use my solution (Swift 3): https://gist.github.com/Blackjacx/2198d86442ec9b9b05c0801f4e392047

After the replacement you can just get `textField.text` to retrieve the composed text.