# How to send service call after filling textfields in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, textfield

I want to send service call to understand whether that pin correct or not. I have  4 textfields. If 4th text field is entered the service call has to go automatically. It means all textfield should fill. The service call has to go in a way that if user changes 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. I know we have to write in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. But I don’t know where to write in that.

Please help me. Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *acceptedInput = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS];

    if (textField == self.textFied1&&([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:acceptedInput] count] > 0))
    {
        int length = (int)[textField.text length];
        if (length==1)
        {
            [self.textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
            if(range.length == 0)
            {
                [self.textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
                return NO;
            }
            if([self.textFied1.text length]==1)
            {
                self.textFied1.text=@"";
                [self.textFied1 becomeFirstResponder];
                return NO;
            }

        }
        if (([[self.textField4 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textField2 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textField3 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textFied1 text] length] > 0)){
            [self connected1];//this step is not executing

        }
    }
    else if (textField == self.textField2&&([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:acceptedInput] count] > 0))
    {
        int length = (int)[textField.text length];
        if (length==1)
        {
            if(range.length == 0)
            {
                [self.textField3 becomeFirstResponder];
                return NO;
            }

            if([self.textField2.text length]==1)
            {
                self.textField2.text=@"";
                [self.textFied1 becomeFirstResponder];
                return NO;
            }
        }
        if (([[self.textField4 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textFied1 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textField3 text] length] > 0)&&([[self.textField2 text] length] > 0)){

            [self connected1];//this step is not executing

        }

    }
    else if (textField == self.textField3&&([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:acceptedInput] count] > 0))
    {
        int length = (int)[self.textField3.text length];
        if (length==1)
        {
            if(range.length == 0)
            {
                [self.textField4 becomeFirstResponder];
                return NO;
            }

            if([self.textField3.text length]==1)
            {
                self.textField3.text=@"";
                [self.textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
                return NO;
            }
        }
        if (([[self.textField4 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textField2 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textFied1 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textField3 text] length] > 0)){
            [self connected1];//this step is not executing
        }
    }
    else if (textField == self.textField4&&([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:acceptedInput] count] > 0))
    {
        int length = (int)[textField.text length];
        if (length==1)

        {

            if(range.length == 0)
                return NO;

            if([self.textField4.text length]==1)
            {
                self.textField4.text=@"";
                [self.textField3 becomeFirstResponder];

                return NO;
            }

        }

        // here my service code
      if (([[self.textFied1 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textField2 text] length] > 0)&& ([[self.textField3 text] length] > 0)&&([[self.textField4 text] length] > 0))
        {
            [self connected1];//this step is not executing
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @Candost thanks for editing

Comment: any one can help me

Comment: Wouldn't you do the `if(longTestOn4TextFields){[self connected1];}` with a button "Ok" or "Connect", or at least on `textFieldDidEndEditing:`?

Comment: @larme its requirement of company i have to send response directively after entering 4th pin in any field

Comment: Before each `if` test, could you log the length of the text field, helping to understand why it doesn't pass the test?

Comment: yes i have tested that value is there

Comment: every time the 4th textfield text is sending empty

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`  you can't get string directly.

First make user's input text as:

```
NSString *content = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
```

And then match every condition with `content`.

For [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198067/using-textfieldshouldchangecharactersinrange-how-do-i-get-the-text-includin)