# when i try to get value from UITextField it returns the previous value not the current. #Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a viewController than contains a textField and a button.
Each time I press the button a different image would appear and the user must write in the textField a caption for the image (images retrieved from a database).
the problem is when I try to save the text value of the field it gives me the previous value that the user entered not the current one.
Anyone can help, please.
Thank you

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var submit: UIButton!

public func  pr (ind: Int) {

    let  ref = Database.database().reference()
    let doc = db.collection("users").document(organized.uid)
    if ind < list.count {
        var color1 = hexStringToUIColor(hex: list[ind])
        textview.backgroundColor = color1
        textview.isEditable = false
        let  userResponse = self.field.text

        var idd = "\(organized.ind)"
        let number = Int.random(in: 0 ... 1000000)
        let v = "userResponse\(number)"

        ref.child(idd).child("values").child(v).setValue(userResponse)
        organized.ind += 1 //new place

        //increment  index  by 1 in  the  database
        doc.updateData(["index": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))])                            
    }
    else {
        print("congrats all colours")
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more code, please? As this is hard to tell what is the problem with the existing code.

Comment: If you want the current text, you should implement the delegated method of the UITextFieldDelegate : optional func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198067/using-textfieldshouldchangecharactersinrange-how-do-i-get-the-text-includin

Comment: Yuri Solodkin i did now even though most of the code is for reading/writing from database , each time I press the button this method will be called,

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following solution, Where you will get an event on text field value change.

```
textfield.addTarget(self, action: 
#selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)



@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    //print(textField.text) 
}
```