# how can i display simultaneously values in one text field to another text field

Tags: iphone

i did a simple application with two text fields.

I need to print in the second textfield  same as which is enter in first text field simultaneously.

For that i am writing the fallowing code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{ 
   [textfield2 setText:textfield1.text]; 

}
```

but it prints from second value.

for example text field1 = 111;

it is displaying in text field as 11;

what is the wrong.

i need what exactly enter in text field1 to text field2 simultaneously.

can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: @MaheshBabu As @EvanMulawski pointed out, you're using the wrong event handler. The one you're using, `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, happens **before** the first text field changed, which is why it starts with "shouldChange", which is future tense in English, instead of "changed," which is past tense in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set Event Handler (or use Interface Builder):

```
[textField1 addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(textFieldEditingDidChange:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Method:

```
- (void)textFieldEditingDidChange:(UITextField *)sender
{
    textField2.text = sender.text;
}
```

When the value of the text field is changed, it calls the method above, which sets the value of the second text field.

Code altered from: [Getting the Value of a UITextField as keystrokes are entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388237/getting-the-value-of-a-uitextfield-as-keystrokes-are-entered)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{ 
    NSMutableString *localString = textfield2.text;
     if([string isEqualToString:@""]){
         [localString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([localString length]-1, 1) 
                                    withString:@""];
     }else{
         [localString appendString:string];
     }
     textfield2.text = localString;

}
```

:D