# iPhone how to get UITextField's text while typing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I'm trying to show changes made to a `UITextField` on a separate `UILabel`. Is there  a way to capture full text of the `UITextField` after each character the user types in? Currently I'm using this method, but it does not capture the last character that the user has entered.

I know that `UITextView` has "didChange" method, but I could not find that method for a `UITextField`.

```
//does not capture the last character

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

        [self updateTextLabelsWithText: textField.text];

    return YES;
}
```

**How can I take text out of UITextField after each character entered?**

Thank you!

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388237/getting-the-value-of-a-uitextfield-as-keystrokes-are-entered

Answer (score 140, accepted):

1. First add one `UITextField` and `UILabel` to storyboard / nib
2. Now assign `IBOutlet` for `UILabel` (Here I have used *myLabel*)
3. Assign `UITextFieldDelegate` to file owner, also implement the same delegate in .h file
4. Use these lines of code:

   ```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        [self updateTextLabelsWithText: newString];

        return YES;
    }

    -(void)updateTextLabelsWithText:(NSString *)string
    {
         [myLabel setText:string];
    }
   ```

Comment: if i delete character one by one. this method not calling

Answer (score 73):

Simply handle the "Editing Changed" event

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(editingChanged:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and the selector:

```
-(void) editingChanged:(id)sender {
   // your code
}
```

You can do this manually, or with the storyboard by CTRL-Dragging the "Editing changed" Sent event to your .h, creating the editingChanged method for you.

Comment: This is actually a better solution as the one accepted. Thanks!. The accepted answer will not clear the label text entirely when you remove the last character from your textfield.

Comment: this should be selected as answer

Answer (score 8):

Swift with addTarget Swift 2.0+

```
   titleTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTyping), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

And implement `selector`

```
func textFieldTyping(textField:UITextField)
{
    //Typing
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**In Swift 2.0+**

```
 class CheckInViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    yourTextField.delegate = self

 }

 func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {
    var updatedTextString : NSString = textField.text as NSString
    updatedTextString = updatedTextString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    self.methodYouWantToCallWithUpdatedString(updatedTextString)
    return true
 }

}
```

Hope it helps you swift pioneers

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 3.0:**

Some of these solutions were one character behind, or for earlier versions of Swift and Obj-C.  Here is what I am using for Swift 3.0

In the class I declared a placeholder to store the text.

```
var tempName = ""
```

In ViewDidLoad I used:

```
nameField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(typingName), for: .editingChanged)
```

Then I made a function called:

```
   func typingName(textField:UITextField){

        if let typedText = textField.text {
            tempName = typedText
            print(tempName)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0+: This worked very nicely for me.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    self.yourLabel.text = "\(textField.text ?? "")\(string)"
    return true
}
```

Comment: And what if user returns?

Comment: or hits backspace?

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField == yourTextFieldOutletName
        {
           if yourTextFieldOutletName.isEmpty == false
           {
             youtlabelname.text = yourTextFieldOutletName.text!
            }


        }

        return true

    }

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
       if textField == yourTextFieldOutletName
            {
               if yourTextFieldOutletName.isEmpty == false
               {
                 youtlabelname.text = yourTextFieldOutletName.text!
                }


            } 
    }
```