# Cannot connect to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am making a basic currency conversion app in an attempt to learn `ios` development, but cannot figure out how to listen to `UITextField` events. this is my code so far:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Currency
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: 

      UIViewController

    , UIPickerViewDelegate
    , UIPickerViewDataSource 

    , UITextViewDelegate

    , UITextFieldDelegate

    {

    @IBOutlet var pickerView     : UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var inputTextField : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outputText: UILabel!


    // definface pickerdata : note it's a constant
    let pickerData = ["euro", "us-dollar", "yen", "yuan", "peso"]

    // initialize src and tgt currency with listeners
    // note not sure what to do with these observers yet
    var src : String = "" // { did set {} }
    var tgt : String = "" 

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // instance of this class is source of data
        pickerView.dataSource   = self
        pickerView.delegate     = self

        // match default srce and tgt to ios default
        src = pickerData[0]
        tgt = pickerData[0]

        // disable spell check
        inputTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no

    }

    //MARK: -  UIPickerView data source method
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        // number of components in pickerData
        return 2
    }

    // UIPickerViewDelegate methods
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        // number of rows
        return pickerData.count
    }

    //MARK: Delegates - places data into picker
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    // responding to row selections and also need to write to UILabel
    // NOTE: we need to 
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if component == 0 { src = pickerData[row] } 
        else              { tgt = pickerData[row] }

        let rate = Data.getExchangeRate(inputUnit: src, outputUnit: tgt)

        print (">> (src,tgt): (", src, ",", tgt, ")   value: ", inputTextField.text)
        outputText.text = "hello world"

    }


    //MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate  methods
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField : UITextField) -> Bool{
        print("TextField did begin editing method called")
        return true
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

        print("textField changing")
        return true
    }    

}
```

The functions under `//MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate  methods` should fire when I edit the text field, but is not doing so right now. Any thoughts?

Comment: As you learn programming, one important skill is consistency. You've made your `outputText` outlet `weak` but not the other two outlets. Make them all weak or none of them weak. Just be consistent. Same goes for little things like whitespace (including blank lines). Pick a style and be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `delegate` is an object that acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object when that object encounters an event in a program. The delegating object is often a `responder` object.

The delegating object keeps a reference to the other object—the delegate—and at the appropriate time sends a message to it. The message informs the delegate of an event that the delegating object is about to handle or has just handled.

The delegate may respond to the message by updating the appearance or state of itself or other objects in the application.

The delegating class has an outlet or property, usually one that is named delegate. 
The delegating class declares methods on a category of NSObject, and the delegate implements only those methods in which it has an interest in coordinating itself with the delegating object or affecting that object’s default behavior.

I hope now you get why textfield delegate methods were not called. As you have not assigned your `ViewController` as delegate of `inputTextField`. Hence the message that `inputTextField` is just handled is not delivered to your `ViewController`.

You can check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) link to know more about Delegate. To know how delegation pattern works check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) link.

You can set your class as delegate of textfield as

```
inputTextField.delegate = self;
```

-----EDIT----

how to detect what the current text is in the text field?

In viewDidLoad add

```
inputTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(typingInput), for: .editingChanged)
```

Define method as

```
func typingInput(textField:UITextField){
    if let typedText = textField.text {        
        print(typedText ) // get the current string
    }
}
```

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363856/iphone-how-to-get-uitextfields-text-while-typing) ans.

Comment: @rmaddy do let me understand, Y shud I not use HTH??

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246066/is-hope-that-answered-your-question-considered-a-prohibited-signature-taglin and similar discussions.

Comment: @rmaddy as a follow-on question that does not justify its own SO post, how do I detect what the *current* text is in the text field? I tried the `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` method, but from this function I can only access the previous entry and the replacement string. Functions such as `textFieldDidBeginEditing` does not fire for me when I use it. And `textFieldShouldReturn` gives me the current entry only when I press return.

Comment: As a followup, I can reconstruct the current text in the field in the `textField` function using the two bits of information I have, but it seems like an antipattern.

Comment: @chibro2 try this.. inputTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(typingInput), for: .editingChanged)
Define method as:

   func typingInput(textField:UITextField){

        if let typedText = textField.text {        
            print(typedText )
        }
    }

Answer (score 4):

Set `inputTextField` delegate.

```
inputTextField.delegate = self
```

Comment: Or connect the text field's delegate in Interface Builder.