# Why my indicator view is not showing?

Tags: ios, swift

Using swift3 with xcode8

Below is my viewconroller.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var YahooWebview: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!


     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let YURL = URL(string: "http://www.yahoo.com")
        let YURLRequest = URLRequest(url: YURL!)
        YahooWebview.loadRequest(YURLRequest)
    }
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(YahooWebview: UIWebView) {
    activity.startAnimating()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(YahooWebview: UIWebView) {
    print("show indicator")
    activity.stopAnimating()
}
```

Why my indicator is not showing when webview is loading? 
I can not even see string "show indicator" from my log in Xcode.

Comment: Add delegate: `YahooWebview.delegate = self`

Comment: Connect the web view's delegate to your controller in Interface Builder.

Comment: try to getout from behind webview `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(activity)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your class as the delegate of UIWebView as

```
YahooWebview.delegate = self
```

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003256/cannot-connect-to-uitextfield) to get details regarding delegates and delegation pattern.

**Note from apple developer:** In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the 
`WKWebView` class instead of using `UIWebView`. Additionally, consider setting the `WKPreferences` property javaScriptEnabled to false if you render files that are not supposed to run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two problems as mentioned in comments.

Both can be solved in your Stroyboard/xib file.

1. Your `UIActivityIndicatorView` is may be hidden behind `UIWebView`. Just change the position of the view so that it comes above in the view heirarchy.
2. You may not have set delegate property of UIWebview class as your ViewController. Right click on webview and check. This needs to be set as you are animating the activity indicator view inside delegate methods.