# Get data writing in UITextField

Tags: swift, validation, uikit, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter

I am creating a form for taking measurements and I therefore have several text files. I need to be able to retrieve what the user writes in the textField. I tried several methods but I can't find a way to get there. Can you give me a lead?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var myTextField = UITextField()


    @IBOutlet weak var wristFlex: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var wristExtension: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstPhalanx: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondPhalanx: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdPhalanx: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var forearmLenght: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var handLenght: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fingerLenght: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var forearmCirecumference: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var wristCirecumference: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fingerCirecumference: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var handCirecumference: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var validatedPressed: UIButton!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        wristFlex.delegate = self
        wristExtension.delegate = self
        firstPhalanx.delegate = self
        secondPhalanx.delegate = self
        thirdPhalanx.delegate = self
        forearmLenght.delegate = self
        handLenght.delegate = self
        fingerLenght.delegate = self
        forearmCirecumference.delegate = self
        wristCirecumference.delegate = self
        fingerCirecumference.delegate = self
        handCirecumference.delegate = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textFieldTextDidChange), name: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

    }

// Notifications:

      @objc  func textFieldTextDidChange(ncParam: NSNotification) {

        print("UItextFieldTextDidChange = \(ncParam)")

    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
      // move back the root view origin to zero
      self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
           // if keyboard size is not available for some reason, dont do anything
           return
        }

      // move the root view up by the distance of keyboard height
      self.view.frame.origin.y = 0 - keyboardSize.height
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }


    @IBAction func validatedPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if wristFlex.text == "" || wristExtension.text == "" || firstPhalanx.text == "" || secondPhalanx.text == "" || thirdPhalanx.text == "" || forearmLenght.text == "" || handLenght.text == "" || fingerLenght.text == "" || forearmCirecumference.text == "" || wristCirecumference.text == "" || fingerCirecumference.text == "" || handCirecumference.text == "" {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Erreur", message: " Tous les champs ne sont pas remplis", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(alertAction)
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    internal func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        print("")
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPhone how to get UITextField's text while typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363856/iphone-how-to-get-uitextfields-text-while-typing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [textFieldDidEndEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting) method from the UITextfieldDelegate.
This method gets called when a user is done with his entry. Then you can access variables with `textField.text`

The example below is an implementation for a case where you have only one textfield. In your case you need to distinguish between the different textfields.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField,
                               reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason){
       if let value = textField.text  {
            print(value)
       }
   }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve what the user writes in the UITextFields, you can access their text properties with something like textField.text.

More specifically in your case something like `wristFlex.text`, or `thirdPhalanx.text` can work, and so on, for all of your UITextFields.

Hope this helps someone!