# What is a simple way to get the entire text that is inside a UITextField as it is being typed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

As the user is typing into a UITextField, I need to know in realtime the entire string in the text field. My way of doing this was to listen for a [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldBeginEditing%3a) callback. The problem with this callback is that it is triggered right before the additional text is actually inserted. Because of this and various other corner cases, I needed to write this horrendously complex code. Is there a simpler (less code) way of doing the same thing?

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString* entireString = nil;

    if (string.length == 0) {
        // When hitting backspace, 'string' will be the empty string.
        entireString = [textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, textField.text.length - 1)];
    } else if (string.length > 1) {
        // Autocompleting a single word and then hitting enter. For example,
        // type in "test" and it will suggest "Test". Hit enter and 'string'
        // will be "Test".
        entireString = string;
    } else {
        // Regular typing of an additional character
        entireString = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
    }

    NSLog(@"Entire String = '%@'", entireString);

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388237/getting-the-value-of-a-uitextfield-as-keystrokes-are-entered?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't even deal with the delegate. Just use `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` to be informed of the change after the fact. Then you don't have to worry about appending the changes to the string, you can just access the text as a whole.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSString *string = someTextFieldReference.text;
}];
```

Or as pointed out in the answers in the post @warpedspeed linked, you could just add a target for the text field's editing changed control event, like so:

```
[myTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",sender.text);
}
```